# Which ER is correct?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I want to create a database. Right now I have 3 columns in my table: question, subject and keyword. The questiosn can be associate with **multiple** Subjects and Keywords.
Which one of these two is the correct ER?

ER **1**
[image]

ER **2**
[image]

Comment: I vote for the  _first one_. It has higher degree of **normalization** than second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your models stand, there is an issue with the attribute names in ER 2. `Contains.SubjectID` should be `Contains.sID` if it's to link to the `Subject` entity.

Assuming that's just a typo, and doesn't immediately disqualify ER 2, which is the "correct" model? Normalisation is important of course, but it's not the be all and end all. The correct data model depends on the system requirements. For example, using ER 1, it would not be possible to link a subject to one or more keywords without creating a question or questions which reference those subjects/keywords. With ER 2 it would be possible.

Maybe ER 1 is correct because it's more normalised, maybe ER 2 is correct because it's more flexible? Without knowing the requirements, there is no yardstick to measure the two models against, and so there isn't really a "correct" one.

Answer (score 1):

*First one* without any doubt,You have some anomalies in *second*.
looking at this could help you: [wikipedia - database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)